# External library and pthread memory leak

Tags: qt, memory-leaks, pthreads, extern

I'm having an issue with a program that uses `pthread` under Qt.

Since I started using an external library I'm dealing with a strange memory leak.

To represent the problem I prepare this simple example:

```
extern "C" short __stdcall somefunction(some_parameters);

void *runThread( void *arg )
    {
    printf("I'm a thread...\n");
    pthread_exit(NULL);
    }

int main()
    {
    somefunction(some_parameters);

    pthread_t thread;
    pthread_attr_t attr;

    while(1)
        {
        pthread_attr_init(&attr);
        pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);
        pthread_create( &thread, &attr, &runThread, NULL);
        pthread_attr_destroy ( &attr );

        Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
```

If I comment the line `somefunction(some_parameters);` **OR** if I don't create threads (by commenting the lines starting with `pthread_...` inside the `while`) then the leak stops.

The library is from a third party provider and I don't have access to it's source code.

Is it maybe that the library is not thread safe? Anyway I believe is strange because I'm not calling `somefunction` from inside the threads.

What could be the cause for this strange behavior?

**EDIT:** Don't know if this is something useful but this piece of code is compiled using Qt5.2 + mingw, the library was compiled using MSVC and I'm linking the program to it's DLL.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT: Finally there was an error in the external library that leaks memory when working with threads, then a second leak was found related to pthreads ([Detached pthreads and memory leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21189328/detached-pthreads-and-memory-leak/21363003?noredirect=1#comment32595502_21363003)) Thank you all for your support.**

Comment: Difficult to guess even without knowing what somefunction is supposed to do. Anyway, how is this issue related to Qt? Somefunction is a Qt function? If not, I would remove that tag, personally.

Comment: You could try with valgrind to see if it reports something useful

Comment: @Lazlo thank you for your comment, I forgot to say that this code is compiled with Qt5.2 (mingw compiler) but the library was compiled using MSVC. I will add this information.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Frank! unfortunately this library is only available for Windows platforms, so I believe is not possible for me to use Valgrind, please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Lazlo someFunction (and the whole library) is actually to check if a security dongle is present.

Comment: How do you compile the code?

Comment: Hello @alk, thank you for your comment. I'm linking to the library this way: LIBS = -L[path_to_library] -l[dll_name_without_extension], except that nothing fancy.

Comment: Did make sure to use the compiler option `-pthread`, but not only the linker option `-lpthread`?

Comment: Hi @alk, thank you for your answer. I added QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -pthread to the Qt project pro file but the leak persists.

Comment: Finally I could contact the library provider and it was a leak from their side, they correct the problem and the leak stop. Thank you all for your suppport!

Answer (score 0):

this question looks familiar. What you describe here points to QT+Windows bug as well. If using CreateThread instead of _beginthreadex is the reason for the leak, then adding and removing some_function(some_parameters) can be explained:

If some_function() calls some of C-runtime functions then commenting it out may stop the leak if the rest of QT does not make those calls. The results of you test may depend on execution path - in some places QT calls _beginthreadex correctly.

Comment: Hello @SergeyD. Finally this was an error in the external library when working with threads that the developer solved (tested that), but there was a second leak related to pthreads that's why I opened a second question and avoid mentioning the library to avoid confusion.