# Detached pthreads and memory leak

Tags: c++, windows, memory-leaks, pthreads

Can somebody please explain to me why this simple code leaks memory?

I believe that since pthreads are created with detached state their resources should be released inmediatly after it's termination, but it's not the case.

My environment is Qt5.2.

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <windows.h>

void *threadFunc( void *arg )
    {
    printf("#");
    pthread_exit(NULL);
    }

int main()
    {
    pthread_t thread;
    pthread_attr_t attr;

    while(1)
        {
        printf("\nStarting threads...\n");
        for(int idx=0;idx<100;idx++)
            {
            pthread_attr_init(&attr);
            pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);
            pthread_create( &thread, &attr, &threadFunc, NULL);
            pthread_attr_destroy ( &attr );
            }
        printf("\nSleeping 10 seconds...\n");
        Sleep(10000);
        }
    }
```

[image: Memory leak graph]

**UPDATE:**

I discovered that if I add a slight delay of 5 milliseconds inside the `for` loop the leak is **WAY** slower:

```
    for(int idx=0;idx<100;idx++)
        {
        pthread_attr_init(&attr);
        pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);
        pthread_create( &thread, &attr, &threadFunc, NULL);
        pthread_attr_destroy ( &attr );
        Sleep(5); /// <--- 5 MILLISECONDS DELAY ///
        }
```

[image: Memory leak graph with slight delay]
This is freaking me out, could somebody please tell me what is happening? How this slight delay may produce such a significant change? (or alter the behavior in any way)

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

**UPDATE2:**

This leak was observed on Windows platforms (W7 and XP), no leak was observed on Linux platforms (thank you @MichaelGoren)

Comment: If you're using Qt, why not use QThread?

Comment: Why is this tagged qt?  There's no Qt code in your example!

Comment: Your code seems correct to me. The best way to find is to profile your code. ;) try to call your threadfunc(), in sequential without using thread. Some printf() versions leak.

Comment: Hi @Merlin069 and thank you for your answer. Good suggestion, anyway I would like to keep the use of pthread because I'm not sure I will keep using Qt in the future for this particular project.

Comment: @AxelBorja thank you for your answer. I'm sure printf() is not leaking. I think calling threadfunc() without using threads is useless (the functions does nothing but pthread_exit()) what kind of information may i get from that?

Comment: So this only happens if you do have `#include <QCoreApplication>` at the 1st line your code?

Comment: Which compiler do you use?

Comment: Hello @alk, thank you for your answer. I'm using MinGW 4.8 32 Bits  compiler (Qt 5.2), and about your first comment the answer is no, the leak almost stops when I include a slight delay inside the for loop that creates the threads, please read above.

Comment: Is the issue resolved if you make "attr" an array?

Comment: Hello @Fracu. I have tested your program (without sleep inside the for loop) on an Intel Linux machine. No memory leak was observed. Hope this fact adds some value.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @MichaelGoren, yes, you are right, this happened to me only on Windows platforms (W7 and XP). I will add this information.

Comment: What happens after a while, is the memory freed after a while? Maybe, the OS keeps the threads for a while so it can remove a bunch of them at once...

Comment: No @invalid_id, I have run the program for maybe six hours and the memory was never released, just the opposite keeps increasing constantly.

Comment: If you are using MinGW then then probably also pthreads-win32. I would check out the library implementation details. For instance the [FAQ](https://www.sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/faq.html) section mentions that the library does not free memory after pthread_t handles (see question 11). It does also mention that this memory is somehow reused but it does not specify how. Anyhow, I would take a closer look at pthread library you are using.

Comment: Try disabling the internal buffer for stdout using setbuf(stdout,NULL). The above code doesn't compile on my computer. You need to remove the & in front of threadFunc

Comment: The problem is that you destroy the attr before the thread has finished.....

Comment: @JensMunk what is the problem with that if the thread is created detached? About your first comment I have tried without printf calls at all and the leak persists.

Comment: Okay, anyway according to the standard behavior of stdout, it is a necessary thing to do. About the attributes, the problem is that it is given by reference and is used throughout the lifetime of the thread.

Comment: I really like the fact that you are using POSIX, which I think is by far the most complete library for threading. I really enjoy this post, which explains why you still should prefer POSIX to the new standard threads. It includes a convenient map so you can see where they overlap. http://gustedt.wordpress.com/2012/10/14/c11-defects-c-threads-are-not-realizable-with-posix-threads/

Answer (score 1):

I checked the program with slight modifications on windows using cygwin, and memory consumption was steady. So it must be a qt issue; the pthread library on cygwin works fine without leaking.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>


void *threadFunc( void *arg )
{
printf("#");
pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main()
{
pthread_t thread;
pthread_attr_t attr;
int idx;

while(1)
    {
    printf("\nStarting threads...\n");
    for(idx=0;idx<100;idx++)
        {
        pthread_attr_init(&attr);
        pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);
        pthread_create( &thread, &attr, &threadFunc, NULL);
        pthread_attr_destroy ( &attr );
        }
    printf("\nSleeping 10 seconds...\n");
    //Sleep(10000);
sleep(10);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello @MichaelMoser thank you for your answer. How long did you leave the program running?

Answer (score 0):

Compiler optimizations or the OS it self can decide to do loop unrolling. That is your for loop has a constant bound (100 here). Since there is no explicit synchronization to prevent it, a newly created, detached thread can die and have its thread ID reassigned to another new thread before its creator returns from pthread_create() due to this unrolling. The next iteration is already started before the thread was actually destroyed.

This also explains why your added slight delay has less issues; one iteration takes longer and hence the thread functions can actually finish in more cases and hence the threads are actually terminated most of the time.

A possible fix would be to disable compiler optimizations, or add synchronization; that is, you check whether the thread still exist, at the end of the code, if it does you'll have to wait for the function to finish.
A more tricky way would be to use mutexes; you let the thread claim a resource at creation and by definition of `PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED` this resource is automatically released when the thread is exited, hence you can use `try_lock` to test whether the thread is actually finished. Note that I haven't tested this approach so I'm not actually sure whether `PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED` actually is working according to its definition...

Concept:

```
pthread_mutex_t mutex;

void *threadFunc( void *arg )
{
  printf("#");
  pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}

for(int idx=0;idx<100;idx++)
{
  pthread_attr_init(&attr);
  pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);
  pthread_create( &thread, &attr, &threadFunc, NULL);
  pthread_attr_destroy ( &attr );
  pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex); //will block untill "destroy" has released the mutex
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}
```

Comment: Helo @invalid_id and thank you for your answer. To test what you suggest (that a thread may die before pthred_create returns and pthread_attr_destroy gets executed) I have added a 100 milliseconds delay inside *threadFunc(), so the thread waits this time before it dies giving enough time to pthread_create to finish, but pitifully the leak persists. Please let me know if I'm missing something from your explanation. Thank you.

Comment: I might have been a bit unclear. My point is that it might occur that the thread destroy is not finished before thread create is called again, hence the pointer to the thread is lost since it is assigned to a new thread already. Can you try to add the 100ms sleep after the ` pthread_attr_destroy ( &attr );` line, instead of 5ms? Just as a check whether the above might be the case.

Comment: Added a 100mS delay after pthread_attr_destroy and decrease the delay after the for loop to 1 second to have more or less the same thread creation rate. Leave it running for 24hs to be sure. The leak stop! So your guess was wise! What I don't understand: if I wait 100mS inside the thread (like I tested) why pthread_attr_destroy doesn't have time to destroy attr? Also what would be a solution using mutexes? I tried: mainthread locks, thread try to lock (waits), after pthread_attr_destroy mainthread unlocks, thread finally locks, unlocks and exits. But leak persists in this case. Thank you!

Comment: @Fracu If you add the wait inside the thread the pointer to the thread can already be assigned to another thread and hence you get leakage. If you wait after the destroy of the thread it has time to actually get destroyed before you assign the pointer to the next thread, so this probably solved it (for now). I'm not sure whether my solution works but the idea is simple. You lock a resource in the thread. Then after the destroy you can check whether the thread is destroyed by using try lock on the same resource, while the resource is blocked the thread isn't actually destroyed yet.

Comment: could you please post a simple piece of code that shows what you are explaining? I would like to test it on Qt but want to be sure that my interpretation is correct.

Comment: See above, this should work because a detached thread should cleanup their resource when destroyed, hence `mutex` should be released when the thread is actually destroyed. So the additional `pthread_mutex_lock` blocks the execution until the resource is actually released by the thread, which is when it is destroyed.

Comment: Thank you @invalid_id, I tested it, but after three or four threads created (On screen "###", or "####") the mutex remains locked and no more threads are created. So from my undestanding I believe the mutex is not released when the thread is actually destroyed.

Comment: Do you have by coincidence a Quad core computer? The 3 and 4 occurences smell like it. According to the definition of a detached thread all resources should be released, but apparently the mutex is somehow not regarded as a resource held by the thread :S BTW if you do have a Quad core you could try to turn of the compiler optimizations.

Comment: I have run the program in two computers, one is Quad Core (i5-2500k) Windows 7 and another is Core 2 Duo Windows XP, and in both of them I observed the leak.

Comment: Hello my friend. Thanks for your concern. Sadly no, I tried to contact pthreads-win32 developers or experienced people using this library by the mailing list pthreads-win32-subscribe@sourceware.org but it seems is not working. Strange because I see historic messages from Dec 2013 (but none from 2014).

Comment: Hmm, that's very odd indeed. So far, unfortunately, I also couldn't come up with another reason why it has this strange behavior. I still think it is strange you got three or four '#' chars with the mutex thing, you should only get one if it really blocks since there's only one resource...

Comment: @invalid_id Try unrolling the loop manually and you will see that loop unrolling clearly has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @TimLovell-Smith, which type of loop unrolling did you try? You cannot do compiler/OS level loop unrolling "by hand" that easily.

Comment: @invalid_id The OS does not unroll loops in your code. The compiler loop unrolling also has nothing to do with this question. Another way you can verify that is by compiling without optimizations.

Comment: Then how to explain the printing of three or four '#' characters in the test above on a quad core machine? Afaik, it's common compiler practice to unroll iterations where possible

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with compiler optimisations. Code is fine. Problem could be
 a) Windows itself. 
 b) Qt implementation of pthread_create() with detached attributes

Checking for (a): Try to create many fast detached threads using Windows _beginthreadex directly and see if you get the same picture. Note: CloseHandle(thread_handle) as soon as _beginthreaex returns to make it detached.

Checking for (b): Trace which function Qt uses to create threads. If it is _beginthread then there is your answer. If it is _beginthreadex, then Qt is doing the right thing and you need to check if Qt closes the thread handle handle immediately. If it does not then that is the cause.

cheers

**UPDATE 2**

Qt5.2.0 does not provide pthreads API and is unlikely responsible for the observed leak.

I wrapped native windows api to see how the code runs without pthread library. You can include this fragment right after includes:

```
#include <process.h>
#define PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE 0
#define PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED 1

typedef struct { int detachstate; } pthread_attr_t;

typedef HANDLE pthread_t;

_declspec(noreturn) void pthread_exit(void *retval)
{
    static_assert(sizeof(unsigned) == sizeof(void*), "Modify code");
    _endthreadex((unsigned)retval);
}

int pthread_attr_setdetachstate(pthread_attr_t *attr, int detachstate)
{
    attr->detachstate = detachstate;
    return 0;
}

int pthread_attr_init(pthread_attr_t *attr)
{
    attr->detachstate = PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE;
    return 0;
}

int pthread_attr_destroy(pthread_attr_t *attr)
{
    (void)attr;
    return 0;
}

typedef struct {
    void *(*start_routine)(void *arg);
    void   *arg;
} winapi_caller_args;

unsigned __stdcall winapi_caller(void *arglist)
{
    winapi_caller_args *list = (winapi_caller_args *)arglist;
    void             *(*start_routine)(void *arg) = list->start_routine;
    void               *arg                       = list->arg;

    free(list);
    static_assert(sizeof(unsigned) == sizeof(void*), "Modify code");
    return (unsigned)start_routine(arg);
}

int pthread_create( pthread_t *thread, pthread_attr_t *attr,
                    void *(*start_routine)(void *), void *arg)
{

    winapi_caller_args *list;

    list = (winapi_caller_args *)malloc(sizeof *list);
    if (list == NULL)
        return EAGAIN;

    list->start_routine = start_routine;
    list->arg = arg;
    *thread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(NULL, 0, winapi_caller, list, 0, NULL);
    if (*thread == 0) {
        free(list);
        return errno;
    }
    if (attr->detachstate == PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED)
        CloseHandle(*thread);

    return 0;
}
```

With Sleep() line commented out it works OK without leaks. Run time = 1hr approx.

If the code with Sleep line commented out is calling Pthreads-win32 2.9.1 library (prebuilt for MSVC) then the program stops spawning new threads and stops responding after 5..10 minutes.

Test environment: XP Home, MSVC 2010 Expresss, Qt5.2.0 qmake etc.

Comment: Thank you @SergeyD to test what you suggest it is needed to recompile Qt from the sources, an I right?

Comment: Yep. You mentioned that you have Windows desktops, not WinCE. That means should be able to replace all CreateThread calls with _beginthreadex calls, then recompile it. Let us know here about the results.

Comment: Hello @SergeyD. Im not experienced on that kind of task, but will give it a try. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: If its turns out too hard, then try this:
get source for thread_win.cpp and other files with "CreateThread", rename them: thread_win2.cpp, fix the calls and include in your project. You may get lucky and build system will give you just a warning about duplicated symbols.
  If that fails, then I will check it when I have time.

Comment: Hi @Fracu, can you tell which pthreads library and what version you are using? Is that a standard build? .pro file would give some info. I downloaded the latest qt 5.2.0 and found that typical build for windows is for msvc2010 -- in that configuration pthreads API is not avilable, and you must be using some other library.

Answer (score 0):

The delay can induce a large change in behavior because it gives the thread time to exit! Of course how your pthread library is implemented is also a factor here. I suspect it is using a 'free list' optimization.

If you create 1000 threads all at once, then the library allocates memory for them all before any significant number of those threads can exit.

If as in your second code sample you let the previous thread run and probably exit before you start a new thread, then your thread library can reuse that thread's allocated memory or data structures which it now knows are no longer needed and it is now probably holding in a free list just in case someone creates a thread again and it can efficiently recycle the memory.

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to join your thread (even if they are finished already).
Correct code should be:

```
        pthread_t arr[100];
        for(int idx=0;idx<100;idx++)
        {
            pthread_attr_init(&attr);
            pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);
            pthread_create( &arr[idx], &attr, &threadFunc, NULL);
            pthread_attr_destroy ( &attr );
        }

        Sleep(2000);

        for(int idx=0;idx<100;idx++)
        {
            pthread_join(arr[idx]);
        }
```

Note from man page:

```
   Failure to join with a thread that is joinable (i.e., one that is not detached), produces a "zombie thread".  Avoid doing this, since each zombie thread consumes some system resources, and  when  enough  zombie  threads  have
   accumulated, it will no longer be possible to create new threads (or processes).
```

Comment: You can't join a thread that is detached. A detached thread is supposed to clean its resource up when it exits without the need for anyone you join it.

Comment: No, you're wrong. You can join a thread that is detached, but pthread_join can not be used to synchronize thread termination.

Comment: "The thread specified by thread must be joinable." " If the thread is created detached, then use of the ID of the newly created thread by the pthread_detach() or pthread_join() function is an
       error."   pthread_join() should fail on a detached thread with EINVAL.